# Rails Nested Json (Jbuilder)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I have these models: 
- Category
- SubCategory
- SubSubCategory

I'm sending a category_list.json.jbuilder with the tree and have categories-->subcategories-->subsubcategories.

Thing is that the "subsubcategy" is showing inside the "subcategory" even if don't has. For example:

I just have one "subsubcategory1" that belongs to "subcatgory1" but appears in "subcategory1" are showing "subsubcategory1, subsubcategor2, etc".

Category model:

```
has_many :sub_categories
has_many :sub_sub_categories
```

SubCategory model.

```
belongs_to :category
belongs_to :sub_category

belongs_to :category
has_many :sub_sub_category, through: :categories
```

SubSubCategory model:

This in my code:

```
 json.categories @categories do |category|
  json.name category.name
  json.description category.description
  json.category_id category.id

  json.sub_categories category.sub_categories do |subcategory|
    json.name subcategory.name
    json.description subcategory.description
    json.sub_category_id subcategory.id

      json.sub_sub_categories category.sub_sub_categories do |subsubcategory|
        json.name subsubcategory.name
        json.description subsubcategory.description
        json.sub_sub_category_id subsubcategory.id
      end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

> I just have one "subsubcategory1" that belongs to "subcatgory1" but appears in "subcategory1" are showing "subsubcategory1, subsubcategor2, etc".

According to your model relations code, your `SubSubCategories` belong to `Categories`, and not `SubCategories`. So, it means that if a category has a subsubcategory, all categories within that category will have that subsubcategory.

I think you want something like this:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :sub_categories
    has_many :sub_sub_categories, through: :sub_categories
end

class SubCategory < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :category
    has_many :sub_sub_categories
end

class SubSubCategory < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :sub_category
end
```